# What causes this misalignment bug in eqnarray?

Tags: align, eqnarray

**Edit:** The following example code is slightly misleading because it contains non-breakable space (which actually causes the bug, see solution). Beware that Option + space produces this character and it isn't marked differently in any way (at least on macos 10.12.) just like in this question.
Original:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{eqnarray}
p&=& 0 \\
a&=& 0 \\
h&=& 0
\end{eqnarray}
\end{document}
```

[image]

One of these simple & similar equations inside an eqnarray is typeset to be aligned differently: the second one RHS is slightly moved to the right. I haven't encountered anything like this in other align environments. This isn't even persistent, haven't been able to pinpoint the cause. (Might be typset engine/LaTeX build related; MWE typeset in TeXShop 4.44 on macos 10.12., see log below.) Luckily this isn't for some important document and not even very bothering, but curious anyway...

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./mwe.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo)) (./mwe.aux)
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./mwe.aux) )</usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm
/cmmi12.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/
cmr12.pfb>
Output written on mwe.pdf (1 page, 18233 bytes).
SyncTeX written on mwe.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on mwe.log.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. A quick question: Why are you employing `eqnarray` in the first place? [Don't do it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/197/5001). Use `align` instead.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If I compile your example, everything is correctly aligned. However, note that [it is preferable to use `align` than to use `eqnarray`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196/eqnarray-vs-align).

Comment: I tested your example with texlive 2016,2017,2018,2019,2020 and did not see the mis-aligned space.

Comment: can you add `\showoutout` and post the log?

Comment: @Mico I took that habit 11 years ago and never noticed these issues (even though i do use nonumber regularly). May be high time to phase it out anyway...

Comment: @Vincent see prev comment :) btw hi to both of you!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh thanks for all this effort, but as you found the issue i'll just mark your answer as the solution if that's ok.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{eqnarray}
p&=& 0 \\
a&=&  0\\
h&=& 0
\end{eqnarray}
\end{document}
```

This has a non breaking space (U+00A0) in the middle row (although posting to this site makes it appear as a normal space so I can not check the example you posted, as it has a normal space in your question even if the file you posted had nbsp)

Comment: Today i looked at the issue again, and had the same suspicion, turns out that was the culprit all along. What i missed was that i can introduce an nbsp as a typo because Option + space produce a nbsp marked identically to a regular space (at least on macos 10.12.), which is likely to occur since the preceding character is Option + 1 = & on my keyboard layout.